# Steam and Nvidia/Optimus/crashes

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, 13.04, bumblebee, steam

I would like to share a solution to a problem i've managed to reproduce on two systems with two different setups, the first setup (Will be refered to as A) was an nvidia optimus setup with ubuntu 13.04 x64. The second setup (Will be referred to as B) Was just an nvidia card with ubuntu 12.10 x64.

Issues encountered on A were; 
1] Games force closing when starting up (EG Loading screens)
2] Games not running on the nvidia card, or lagging.

Issues encountered on B were; 
1] Games force closing when starting up.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions;

A 1] Right click your game's `properties` on the steam client and untick `access steam community in game`.

A 2] With bumblebee installed, firstly make steam start as optirun. Eg: Add a startup program with the command `optirun steam` (No capitals) and then make shortcuts to your games on your desktop, this can be achieved by right clicking the game on steam and clicking `"create desktop icon"` once the icon for the game has been made, right click it, go properties, and at `"Command"` add `optirun` before the command. This cannot be done as a "Custom launch command" Eg: `-optirun` or `optirun`, they just don't seem to work. The finished command should be something like `optirun steam steam://rungameid/225260` but with a different ID obviously.

B 1] Right click your game's `properties` on the steam client and untick `access steam community in game`.

Comment: unable to accept as answer for two days. but this is the solution.